Multi-ring buffers of uneven sizes in QGIS
I am trying to make multi-ring buffers (donuts) around points in QGIS. I want the rings to be from 0 - 2km, 2km - 5km, 5km - 10km. I'm using the multi-ring buffer in QGIS and it doesn't have the option to specify the radius of each circle separately so I can make them each have a difference of 5 or 2 but its has to be the same across. Is there a way to make the radius of each circle different in QGIS.
I tried using difference by making a 0-2km buffer and then a 0-5km buffer but I have over 1000 points which are close together and so the buffer for each unique point overlaps. This means that difference removes regions for all overlapping buffers for other points (which I dont want). The picture shows you what I'm working with where the brown dots are my unique points and the pink buffers are the 2km buffers while the orange ones are the 5km buffers.


Do you care about the buffers of each point, or could you dissolve the buffers?

I do care about the buffer for each point, I need to do further analysis on these rings for each point.

There is a multi-distance plugin tool that might work.  There is also a multi-ring buffer plugin.  I haven't used either.


Geometry by expression:
collect_geometries(
difference(buffer($geometry, distance:=10000),
buffer($geometry, distance:=5000)),
difference(buffer($geometry, distance:=5000),
buffer($geometry, distance:=2000)),
buffer($geometry, distance:=2000))

The expression is creating a 10000 buffer and difference it by 5000 buffer, then a 5000 difference by 2000, and finally a 2000 m buffer. Collects them into a multipart polygon.
Split the multipolygons by Multipart to Singleparts.
Calculate a column for the distances using Field Calculator:
CASE
  WHEN $area<13e6 then 2000
  WHEN $area<70e6 then 5000
  ELSE 10000
END

If you have coordinate system with units other than meters you'll have to adjust the area limits.

Similar the the solutin by @Bera, but based on an array of distances, so the different rings are generated automatically. Using Geometry by expression QGIS automatically generates buffers with all the distances defined in line 5: fing-buffer (domut) from first to second element (0 to 2000), 2nd to 3rd element (2000 to 5000) etc. Change the values ar add more values in line 5 to see how the result changes.
collect_geometries(
    array_filter(
        with_variable(
            'arr',
            array(0,2000,5000,10000),
            array_foreach(
                @arr,
                difference(
                    buffer(@geometry, array_get(@arr,array_find(@arr, @element)+1)),
                    buffer(@geometry, @element)
                )
            )
        ),
        @element is not null
    )
)

Result, demonstrated here with Geometry Generator and different sizes for the buffers. Different colors (not part of the solution) are created with data driven override for color, based an varibale @geometry_part_num:


So, if I understood your question correctly for general understanding one more way to solve the question using SQL code in the form of CTE.
Input geodata: table with structure id, geometry with name points in meter plane-rectangular coordinate system.
Create on the QGIS toolbar - Layer>Create Layer>Create Virtual Layer...and add your table, using the  button.
In the  field, copy and paste the SQL query, replacing the name of your table (layer) and run the query for execution, using the  button.

WITH 
buf_2km AS (select id, 0 in_dist, 2000 out_dist, st_buffer(geometry, 2000) geometry from points),
buf_5km AS (select id, 2000 in_dist, 5000 out_dist, st_buffer(geometry, 5000) geometry from points),
buf_10km AS (select id, 5000 in_dist, 10000 out_dist, st_buffer(geometry, 10000) geometry from points),
dif_5_2km AS (select a.id, a.in_dist-b.in_dist in_dist, 5000 out_dist, st_difference(a.geometry,b.geometry) geometry from buf_5km a JOIN 
buf_2km b on st_intersects(a.geometry,b.geometry) and a.id=b.id),
dif_10_5km AS (select a.id, a.out_dist-b.out_dist in_dist, 10000 out_dist, st_difference(a.geometry,b.geometry) geometry from buf_10km a JOIN 
buf_5km b on st_intersects(a.geometry,b.geometry) and a.id=b.id)
select id, in_dist, out_dist, geometry from buf_2km union select id, in_dist, out_dist, geometry from dif_5_2km union select id, in_dist, out_dist, geometry from dif_10_5km 


Save the result to a file or DBMS table, and then apply the styling as you need, for example as in the figure below.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
